# How can I add two UIBarButtonItems to UINavigationItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I want two rightBarButtonItem's on my UINavigationBar. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) with two buttons and configure it with the `momentary` property set to YES.

This is what is used in the Mail application to go to next/previous message.

**Update**

In order to assign the UISegmentedControl][1](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) as a right button, you have to wrap it inside a UIBarButtonItem (sample code taken from the [NavBar sample application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html)):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // "Segmented" control to the right
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
                                                [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"up.png"],
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"],
                                                 nil]];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, kCustomButtonHeight);
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES;

    UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;
    [segmentBarItem release];
}
```

Comment: Can a UISegmentedControl be casted as UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: I have update my answer to show how to use an UISegmentedControl as rightBarButtonItem.